# How to add a new column and aggregate values in R

Tags: r, plot, aggregation, data-analysis

I am completely new to gnuplot and am only trying this because I need to learn it. I have a values in three columns where the first represents the filename (date and time, one hour interval) and the remaining two columns represent two different entities Prop1 and Prop2.

```
Datetime             Prop1        Prop2

20110101_0000.txt     2            5
20110101_0100.txt     2            5
20110101_0200.txt     2            5
...
20110101_2300.txt     2            5
20110201_0000.txt     2            5
20110101_0100.txt     2            5
...
20110201_2300.txt     2            5
...
```

I need to aggregate the data by the hour of the day (the **_0100) which is the last four numeric digits. So, I want to create another column called hour which tells me the hour of the day. It means `0000 = 0h, 0100 = 1h, ...... 2200 = 22h` etc.

I then want to get the sum of Prop1 and Prop2 for each hour, so in the end get something like.

```
Hour  Prop1   Prop2
0h     120     104
1h     230     160
...
10h    90      110
...
23h    100    200
```

and the get a line plot of Prop1 and Prop2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general solution with gsub :

```
Data$Hour <- gsub(".+_(\\d+).txt","\\1",Data$Datetime)
```

EDIT :

You can use `Data$Hour <- substr(Data$Hour,1,2)` to get just the hour. As said in the comments, if you always have exactly the same structure in Datetime, you could use `substr()` immediately:

```
Data$Hour <- substr(Data$Datetime,10,11)
```

Then you can use `aggregate`, `tapply`, `by`, ... whatever to do what you want. To sum both Prop1 and Prop2, you can use aggregate, eg:

```
aggregate(Data[2:3],list(Data$Hour),sum)
```

with the dataset :

```
zz<-textConnection("Datetime             Prop1        Prop2
20110101_0000.txt     2            5
20110101_0100.txt     2            5
20110101_0200.txt     2            5
20110101_2300.txt     2            5
20110201_0000.txt     2            5
20110201_0100.txt     2            5
20110201_0200.txt     2            5
20110201_2300.txt     2            5")
Data <- read.table(zz,header=T,as.is=T)
```

Comment: thanks didn't know about gsub, looks very handy. one minor query with this I get strings like 0000, 0100, ...2300 in Hour, how to get write the first two digits only like 00, 01, ...10, ..22, 23. Also, how do I aggregate both Prop1 and Prop2 w.r.t hour because I want a line plot with both in the same plot. i am new to R so forgive these really simple questions :).

Comment: Since the structure of the `Datetime` column seems stable, you could just use `substr` to get the hour: `substr(Datetime,10,13)`

Comment: @James I have posted a new question which goes a bit beyond this where there is a column for categories. Could you guys help me out with that as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030389/getting-a-stacked-area-plot-in-r