# Getting a stacked area plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, reshape, stacked-area-chart

This question is a continuation of the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027480/how-to-add-a-new-column-and-aggregate-values-in-r) I asked.

Now I have a case where there is also a category column with Prop. So, the dataset becomes like

```
Hour  Category        Prop2

00     A            25
00     B            59
00     A            55
00     C            5
00     B            50
...
01     C            56
01     B            45
01     A            56
01     B            35
...
23     D            58
23     A            52
23     B            50
23     B            35
23     B            15
```

In this case I need to make a stacked area plot in R with the percentages of these different categories for each day. So, the result will be like.

```
        A         B       C        D
00     20%       30%     35%       15% 
01     25%       10%     40%       25%
02     20%       40%     10%       30% 
.
.
.
20 
21
22     25%       10%     30%       35%
23     35%       20%     20%       25%
```

So now I would get the share of each Category in each hour and then plot this is a stacked area plot like this where the x-axis is the hour and y-axis the percentage of Prop2 for each category given by the different colours[image: this]

Comment: I'd say this is rather a case of fortune(197)... ;-)

Answer (score 29):

You can use the `ggplot2` package from Hadley Wickham for that.

```
R> library(ggplot2)
```

An example data set :

```
R> d <- data.frame(t=rep(0:23,each=4),var=rep(LETTERS[1:4],4),val=round(runif(4*24,0,50)))
R> head(d,10)
   t var val
1  0   A   1
2  0   B  45
3  0   C   6
4  0   D  14
5  1   A  35
6  1   B  21
7  1   C  13
8  1   D  22
9  2   A  20
10 2   B  44
```

And then you can use `ggplot` with `geom_area` :

```
R> ggplot(d, aes(x=t,y=val,group=var,fill=var)) + geom_area(position="fill")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but what about getting the share (percentage or ratio) of each category for each hour from the initial table to the form you show in dataset 'd' here?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this from your question. In fact I think that `ggplot2` can do that for you : I've edited my post to show how to do it.

Comment: sorry to bother again you still make an simplification regarding the data, in the initial form there is repetition of the Category for each hour. So, there can be multiple rows of Category A in hour 0, so how do I aggregate each of these category for each hour first to get it into the form that you have shown here?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `stackpoly` from the `plotrix` package:

```
library(plotrix)
#create proportions table
pdat <- prop.table(xtabs(Prop2~Hour+Category,Dat),margin=1)
#draw chart
stackpoly(pdat,stack=T,xaxlab=rownames(pdat))
#add legend
legend(1,colnames(pdat),bg="#ffffff55",fill=rainbow(dim(pdat)[2]))
```

Comment: This seems to work and gives me the stack plot, but there are no legends to say which colored stack represents which Category?

Comment: You need to sort your categories first so that you know which is which and then make your own legend with the legend() command.

Comment: @sfactor Added an example legend, read `?legend` for more details on how this works

Answer (score -2):

If you want to take the borders away you can use **scale_x_discrete** and **coord_cartesian** this way

```
 p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=Date,y=Volume,group=Platform,fill=Platform)) + geom_area(position="fill")
 base_size <- 9
 p + theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=9)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))
```

Comment: For me this bunches up the entire graph to take up just a tiny fraction of the plot area on the right.