# How do I make this kind of Market Share Chart over time with ggplot2, and what is it called?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: A graph of phone companies market shares over time]

I've looked around, and I haven't been able to find what this kind of chart is called, or how to make it in ggplot2. I have similar share over time data, and I would like to visualize it with a chart like this. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Look into `geom_area` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030389/getting-a-stacked-area-plot-in-r

Comment: `geom_ribbon` or `geom_area` could help.